# vector notation – for every element bigger $0$

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors

I was wondering what the correct notation would be for the following:

a vector $x$ for which every element smaller $0$ is equal to $0$.

so, for example:
$x = [1, 2, -1, 3, 4, -2]$,
accordingly, $x' = [1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0]$

so how would you write: $x$ where $x_1,\ldots,x_n = 0$ if $x_1,\ldots,x_n < 0$ more concisely / correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say you define $x'\in\mathbb R^n$ as $$x'_n = \max\{0, x_n\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like:

If $x=[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then $x'=[x_1'\ldots,x_n']$ where:

$$x_i'=\begin{cases}x_i&x_i\geq0\\
0&x<0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

For functions, $f^+$ or $f_+$ is defined as $f^+(x) = \max{\{f(x),0\}}$. Since a vector can be thought of as a function $\{1,\dotsc,n \} \to \mathbb{R}$, you could adapt this notation: $x' = x^+$, or $x_i' = x_i^+$, perhaps.